# Select con dos consultas

Tags: php, javascript, html

[image: ejemplo]

hola atodos soy principiante y espero puedan ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho nececito hacer un select que contenga el nombre de un proveedor y la cantidad de productos, ambos provienen de una tabla de mysql  anexo una imagen del resultado espero puedan guiarme para realizar esto

Comment: Qué has intentado y por qué no te ha funcionado?

Comment: Tienes que mostrarnos el código de lo que has realizado de otra forma es complicado poder ayudarte.

Comment: Además de mostrarnos lo que intentaste sería bueno que nos muestres qué fue lo que sí supiste hacer. Por ejemplo ¿los datos del mysql los pudiste obtener correctamente?. Mostrar parte del código hecho es muy importante.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas utilizar `<optgroup>` para agrupar los productos de un solo proveedor. Espero que esto sea lo que preguntabas.

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="proveedor 1">
    <option value="prod11">producto 1.1</option>
    <option value="prod12">producto 1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="proveedor 2">
    <option value="prod21">producto 2.1</option>
    <option value="prod22">producto 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```